# How to invoke actionSupport on a required field only if input changed and not blank?

Tags: apex, visualforce

**SimpleVFPage**:

```
<apex:page controller="SimpleController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:inputText value="{!name}" required="true">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!nameChanged}" reRender="theForm"></apex:actionSupport>
            </apex:inputText>
        </apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:pageMessages></apex:pageMessages>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**SimpleController**:

```
public class SimpleController {
    public String name{get;set;}

    public Pagereference nameChanged(){
        System.debug('name entered is '+ name);
        return null;
    }

}
```

[image]

As we can see in the above gif, if input entered is blank, it is showing ugly javascript error saying input is required. I want actionSupport to fire only when value entered is not blank and value changed without changing required attribute.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use **actionSupport** for this. You should use ***actionFunction***. It can be invoked by checking if the entered value is blank or not from inline ***script***.

```
<apex:form id="theForm">
    <apex:inputText value="{!name}" required="true" onkeyup="fireNameChanged(this.value);" />
    <apex:actionFunction name="nameChangedAf" action="{!nameChanged}" reRender="theForm" />
    <apex:pageMessages></apex:pageMessages>
    <script>
    function fireNameChanged(name) {
        if(name) {
            nameChangedAf();
        }
    }
    </script>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: If I use `actionFunction` then server processes whole form and complains about other required fields that are blank. Here is the gif showing if I have two fields but want only one field change should be sent to controller : https://imgur.com/a/21UOgUj 
Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/i0g18E6Q